# angular ng-repeat or ng-options how to use?

Tags: angularjs

Here is a problem. I would like to list some options in a select from a service: the service returns an array like this .

```
["AZERBAIDJAN", "BRAZIL", "CAMEROON", "EQUATOR", "FRANCE", "GHANA"]
```

I don't know what would be better to use ng-repeat or ng-options.  I know to do it with a collections with ng-repeat  !!
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: AngularJS comes with a [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: At least look at the documentation or google a bit before posting a question..

Answer (score 1):

you should use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) for select

```
  <select ng-model="yourModel" 
          ng-options="country  as country for country in yourData">    
  </select>
```